# How can I find a file while in my java code

Tags: java, linux, file-io, directory, filepath

I am stuck on a how to robustly find a file path from my Java program. If I am using Linux, I can launch my program from my home folder, and then I can't say find my file at ./myProgram/myFile. Is there a good way to find my file no matter what directory my console is in?

Comment: [Add the directory the file is in to your path.](http://askubuntu.com/questions/60218/how-to-add-a-directory-to-my-path)

Comment: If you know where your file is then you can find it. If you don't know where it is then you cannot find it. What do you mean exactly? Could you clarify?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are trying to access the file using the path:

```
./myProgram/myFile
```

in your program, but you aren't executing the program from the `myProgram` directory, then you're Java code won't see the file. Try providing it with the full path instead of the relative path. If `myProgram` is a directory found in your user's Documents directory then a full path would likely look something like this:

```
/home/*username*/Documents/myProgram/myFile
```

You could also build in functionality that lets you select the file by navigating through the directories and listing the files. The would provide the user with options to choose which file to utilize in the program.

You can just as well `cd` to the `myProgram` directory before executing the file and then the relative path `./myProgram/myFile` should work.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
File f = new File(System.getProperty("user.home") + System.getProperty("file.separator") + "myFile.txt");
```